# How to convert MySQL search criteria to Elasticsearch query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to convert MySQL search criteria to Eleasticsearch (version 7) query, however, both queries (MySQL and Elasticsearch) gives different results.  On the SQL statement, it shows a single record, and on Elasticsearch, it shows 0 records.  Any help or guidance is much appreciated on this.

SQL criteria

```sql
COUNT(*) WHERE (document_title like '%never listened%' or document_content like '%never listened%') and documnent_tone = 'negative'
```

Converting to Elasticsearch - using PHP Elasticsearch library

```php
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
...

$elasticServer = $this->getOption('elasticsearch')->getElasticServer1();
$hosts = array(
    $elasticServer['host'] . ':' . $elasticServer['port']
);
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();

$params = array (
    "index" => "index_politics",
    "body" => array(
        "query" => array(
            "bool" => array(
                "must" => array(
                    array(
                       "wildcard" => array(
                            "document_title" => "never listened",
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                       "wildcard" => array(
                            "document_content" => "never listened"
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        "match" => array(
                            "document_tone" => "negative"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$response = $client->count($params);
$negative = $response['count'];

var_dump($negative);
```

Comment: array(
                       "wildcard" => array(
                            "document_title" => "never listened",
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                       "wildcard" => array(
                            "document_content" => "never listened"
                        )
                    )  should be part of should

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, the following worked for me

```php
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
...

$elasticServer = $this->getOption('elasticsearch')->getElasticServer1();
$hosts = array(
    $elasticServer['host'] . ':' . $elasticServer['port']
);
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();

$params = array (
    "index" => "index_politics",
    "body" => array(
        "query" => array(
            "bool" => array(
                "must" => array(
                    array(
                        "multi_match" => array(
                            "query" => "never listened",
                            "fields" => array("document_title", "document_content")
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "filter" => array(
                    "term" => array(
                        "document_tone" => "negative"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$response = $client->count($params);
$negative = $response['count'];

var_dump($negative);
```

Converted to Elasticsearch query

```
GET /index_politics/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "never listened",
            "fields": [
              "document_title",
              "document_content"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "document_tone": "negative"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```